# Is there any good big data store for update and delete queries?

Tags: hbase, hadoop2, impala, apache-kudu

I am using hive and hbase as back end stores. Hive is really good for raw data storage. But you cant run update and delete queries if you want good performance. Currently I am using phoenix on top of hbase. It is giving me good performance and sql querying syntax support. But while bringing data to hbase is not easy task. Is there any other big data store which will provide delete and update support like impala or kudu. I dont know much about impala.

Answer (score 2):

Splice Machine and Trafodion are other products that support updates/deletes in HBase...